# Blackberry File (Webworks)

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I'm trying (Very simply) to get a file list of the camera directory using webworks.
The code I'm trying is as follows:

```
function displayPhotos(id) {
try {
    var Dir, path, items;

    if ((window.blackberry === undefined) || (blackberry.io === undefined) || (blackberry.io.file === undefined)) {
        appendContent("photoDetails", "<p><i><b>blackberry.io.file</b> object not found (likely cause is WebWorks APIs are not supported by this user agent).</i></p>");
        debug.log("displayPhotos", "blackberry.io.file object is undefined.", debug.error);
        return false;
    }

    Dir = blackberry.io.dir;

    path = "";      
    path = "file:///Device/home/user/camera"";


    items = Dir.listFiles(path);

    console.log(items);

    //setContent(id, formatAsHTML(path, items));

}
catch(e) {
    console.log("displayPhotos", e, debug.exception);
}
}
```

All I get back is error 1004 - I assume this is permissions based, but I fail to believe I can't get a READ on the camera fails - any one know anything?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I figured it out, hope this helps anyine getting the dreaded blackberry webworks error 1004.

You need to change device in the path to store. That's it really. This example works:

```
function displayPhotos(myFolder) {
    try {
        var Dir, path, items;       
        Dir = blackberry.io.dir;

    path = "";      
    if (myFolder != undefined){
        path = myFolder;
    } else {
        path = "file:///store/home/user/pictures";
        //file:///store/home/user/camera
    }

    items = Dir.listFiles(path);        
    return items;
}
catch(e) {
    console.log("displayPhotos", e, debug.exception);
}
}


function displayFiles(myFolder) {
try {
    console.log("displayFiles", "in " + myFolder);
    return displayPhotos(myFolder);
}
catch(e) {
    console.log("displayFiles", e, debug.exception);
}
}
```

You can call it like so:

```
 displayFiles();
```

Or specify a folder like so:

```
 displayFiles("file:///store/home/user/camera");
```

Returns an array of filenames.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: What of photos stored in the memory card? Does this fetch those too?

Comment: No. You can change the URL from "file:///store/home/user/camera" to the location of your SD card and it will work.